# Order by child property in list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have an two tables - blog and posts (one to many relationship).

I would like to get all blogs with minimum 3 and take only 3 posts for blog and order list by post publish date.

What I was trying:

```
_context.Blogs.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Posts.Count >= 3).OrderByDescending(p => p.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishDate)).ToList();
```

but I'm getting an error message:

```
ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I see it'll be problem to sort by post publish date. 
I have also in Blog table LastBuildDate property. So how can I order by LastBuildDate?

Comment: Posts table is included

Comment: Wouldn't this rather mean that you should first order by Blog and then, when displaying the Posts, order there by PublishDate? You could extend Blog to have PostedAt which refers to the first Post, so you can order on the blogs, and then where you display the posts, sort on the posts...

Comment: I'm a little rusty on my linq, but how does it know what to order the Blogs by?  It seems to me that ordering the posts inside of the blog ordering isn't necessarily correct?

Comment: The vlogs have posts so I want to order blog by the publish date of post.

Comment: But you just said you have multiple posts, each with a publish date. How will it know which post's publish date to order by..

Comment: Okay, I see, I;ve updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I haven't tested it.

```
_context.Blogs.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Posts.Count >= 3).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastBuildDate).ToList();
```

Comment: My linq is very rusty :-/  Try removing everything inside the OrderByDescending()   I'm pretty sure you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

The nested ordering is throwing off this:

```
.OrderByDescending(p => p.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishDate))
```

The outer order is evaluating a object that the Posts property is, which doesn't implements IComparable.  For instance, if you did:

```
.OrderByDescending(p => p.Posts.Max(x => x.PublishDate))
```

Max returns a DateTime.  However, OrderbyDescending on posts returns something it can't evaluate here...